# Realm Migration is not working in Android?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-list, realm-migration

I am at present working on a android chat application like whatsapp but I stuck at a situation in where Realm Migration is issue. I am not knowing so much about realm but testing it for a successful offline chat application. I am not able to use more than one model in realm because it is saying about the migrator. I tried all the ways but my migrator is not working and I also not having idea that what statements I have to use after this (schema.) statement for migrate my model according to my situations.
Here is the Code for my Realm ChatList Model:-

```
public class RealmChatListModel extends RealmObject {

@Index
private String userID;

private String Username;

private String Descryption;

private String phoneNo;

private String lastMessage;

private String Date;

private String ImageURI;

private long lastMessageTime;


public RealmChatListModel() {
}

public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    Username = username;
}

public String getDescryption() {
    return Descryption;
}

public void setDescryption(String descryption) {
    Descryption = descryption;
}

public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}

public String getLastMessage() {
    return lastMessage;
}

public void setLastMessage(String lastMessage) {
    this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getImageURI() {
    return ImageURI;
}

public void setImageURI(String imageURI) {
    ImageURI = imageURI;
}

public long getLastMessageTime() {
    return lastMessageTime;
}

public void setLastMessageTime(long lastMessageTime) {
    this.lastMessageTime = lastMessageTime;
}
}
```

And here is my code for realm Chat Model :-

```
public class RealmChat extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
@Index
private String messageKey;

private String time;
private String date;
private String textMessage;
private String type;
private String sender;
private String receiver;
private String uri;
private boolean isSeen;
private String duration;
private String receivername;
private String fileSize;
private boolean isNextDay;
private boolean isDeleted;
private Date extactdate;
private String repMesKey;
private String repMesUri;
private String repMesText;
private String repMesType;
private String repMesSender;
private long timestamp;
private String repMesSendPhone;
private boolean isReplied;
private String phoneNo;
private boolean isForwarded;


public String getMessageKey() {
    return messageKey;
}

public void setMessageKey(String messageKey) {
    this.messageKey = messageKey;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTextMessage() {
    return textMessage;
}

public void setTextMessage(String textMessage) {
    this.textMessage = textMessage;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getReceiver() {
    return receiver;
}

public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
}

public String getUri() {
    return uri;
}

public void setUri(String uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
}

public boolean isSeen() {
    return isSeen;
}

public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
    isSeen = seen;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(String duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public String getReceivername() {
    return receivername;
}

public void setReceivername(String receivername) {
    this.receivername = receivername;
}

public String getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}

public void setFileSize(String fileSize) {
    this.fileSize = fileSize;
}

public boolean isNextDay() {
    return isNextDay;
}

public void setNextDay(boolean nextDay) {
    isNextDay = nextDay;
}

public boolean isDeleted() {
    return isDeleted;
}

public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
    isDeleted = deleted;
}

public Date getExtactdate() {
    return extactdate;
}

public void setExtactdate(Date extactdate) {
    this.extactdate = extactdate;
}

public String getRepMesKey() {
    return repMesKey;
}

public void setRepMesKey(String repMesKey) {
    this.repMesKey = repMesKey;
}

public String getRepMesUri() {
    return repMesUri;
}

public void setRepMesUri(String repMesUri) {
    this.repMesUri = repMesUri;
}

public String getRepMesText() {
    return repMesText;
}

public void setRepMesText(String repMesText) {
    this.repMesText = repMesText;
}

public String getRepMesType() {
    return repMesType;
}

public void setRepMesType(String repMesType) {
    this.repMesType = repMesType;
}

public String getRepMesSender() {
    return repMesSender;
}

public void setRepMesSender(String repMesSender) {
    this.repMesSender = repMesSender;
}

public String getRepMesSendPhone() {
    return repMesSendPhone;
}

public void setRepMesSendPhone(String repMesSendPhone) {
    this.repMesSendPhone = repMesSendPhone;
}

public boolean isReplied() {
    return isReplied;
}

public void setReplied(boolean replied) {
    isReplied = replied;
}

public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}

public boolean isForwarded() {
    return isForwarded;
}

public void setForwarded(boolean forwarded) {
    isForwarded = forwarded;
}

public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

And Here is my code for my migrator :-

```
public class RealmMigration implements io.realm.RealmMigration {

@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    // Migrate from version 0 to version 1
    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.get("RealmChatListModel")
                .addField("Username", String.class)
                .addRealmListField("lastMessageTime", long.class);
        oldVersion++;
    }

    if (oldVersion == 1) {
        schema.get("RealmChat")
                .addField("extactdate", Date.class)
                .addRealmListField("timestamp",long.class);
    }
}

public static RealmConfiguration getDefaultConfig() {
    return new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .migration(new RealmMigration())
            .build();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() { return RealmMigration.class.hashCode(); }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) { return object != null && object instanceof RealmMigration; }
```

}

Please Help me...................................................................................
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<------------------(~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~)------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it my migration is working only by a single change :-

```
@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    // Migrate from version 0 to version 1
    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.get("RealmChatListModel")
                .addField("userID", String.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
        oldVersion++;
    }
}
```

Here I removed Realm Chat from migrating the old version because it is the last model and added in realmChatListSchema that userID field is required.Noting else reqired. I am happy       .